# Unable to connect to Facebook via Koala on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, ruby-on-rails-5, koala

My final aim is to create a cron job that retrieves my Facebook feed every day.

I've been trying to connect to my Facebook app using Rails (5.0.0.1) and Koala gem (2.4.0) on a single controller so the server authenticates himself and get the token to access the Graph API.

The problem is that the Koala method `get_user_info_from_cookie` returns `nil` therefore I don't know how to get the infamous Access Token. Is there anything wrong?

Here what is in my controller.

```rb
before_action :parse_facebook_cookies

def parse_facebook_cookies
    @oauth = Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new( ENV['FB_APP_ID'], ENV['FB_SECRET_KEY'] )
    @facebook_cookies ||= @oauth.get_user_info_from_cookie(cookies)
end
```

My environment variables `ENV['FB_APP_ID']` and `ENV['FB_SECRET_KEY']` work and cookies is not empty, I've already checked.

Comment: I sorted it out replacing `@oauth.get_user_info_from_cookie(cookies)` with `@oauth.get_app_access_token`.

Comment: get_user_info_from_cookie will return nil if cookies would contain signed code from another fb application. Did you perform FB.login on client after having same APP_ID for FB.init as set in your server?

Comment: This method runs on the server every time you call the `import page`. On browser window you'll just see the result. So the `OAuth.new()` method runs before the page is displayed. As I use Chrome just for development I don't have any Facebook login already set up so that method is the only time I perform the login. That method though is repeated every time you request that `import page`. Don't know if that's what you mean.

Comment: I was wondering why would you call 'get_user_info_from_cookie(cookies)' every time, as user token can only me redeemed from cookies once. Especially if you don't factually have cookies set, i.e. you don't click "Login" on website - or how you was expecting cookies to contain data valid for getting FB token? Maybe I misunderstand your flow.

Comment: Being the first time I got straight to [Koala documentation for Rails](https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Koala-on-Rails) and I found that method. Of course this implied to run the FB javascript SDK first, which is were I got it wrong. I thought Koala would set up cookies via `config/initializers/koala.rb` file, which it actually doesn't.

Comment: Got it :) Just in case, you can either generate app_access_token like you did, or you can manually generate long_term user token and use it as well.